# Telerik toolbar error

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I'm trying to install the editable grid from Telerik. I have this one error:

> Error  13
>   'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridDataKeyBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'ToolBar' and no extension method 'ToolBar' accepting a first argument of type 'Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI.Fluent.GridDataKeyBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Users\dmccray11\Desktop\TheManhattanProject\Views\Home\PartialSlagView.cshtml    42  10  TheManhattanProject

This is the line of code that renders this error:

```
.Grid(Model)
.Name("Grid")
.DataKeys(keys => keys.Add(c => c.analysisid)
.ToolBar(commands => commands.Insert().ButtonType(type).ImageHtmlAttributes(new { style = "margin-left:0" })))
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause of this error?

Comment: any solution? i have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have adjusted your `Views` directory web.config to include the Telerik assembly.

Comment: I have these namespaces in my Views web.config  <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Optimization"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
       <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.UI" />
       <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc" />
      <add namespace="Telerik.Web.Mvc.Configuration"/>
      <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
      <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />